# Finding beginning and end tags in custom HTML-like structure

Tags: c#, html, templating, templating-engine

I am working on a HTML templating engine in C#. I want to achieve some of the same functionality as libraries such as Handlebars.Net (the C# implementation of Handlebars.js), except using basic string manipulation (find/replace) rather than a full-out compiler.

The syntax would be something such as:

```
{{#each item in items}}

    <li>{{item.Name}}</li>

{{/each}}
```

I am looking to do simple string replacements with Regex, but I realize Regex would have shortcomings in this area, such as finding the end tag in the example below (it would find the first embedded {{/each}} rather than the last when parsing the first tag):

```
{{#each item in items}} //while parsing this tag...

  <p>{{item.Name}}'s Hobbies:</p>

  <ul>
    {{#each hobby in item}}

      <li>{{hobby.Name}}</li>

    {{/each}} //this end tag would be found first
  </ul>

{{/each}} //rather than this one
```

I need to find the beginning and end of any given "tag" (such as {{#each}}...{{/each}}) and create a DOM-like structure out of it in order to parse the contents of each tag. The "DOM" could have multiple tags embedded inside of each other (think embedded foreach loops x4). What is a good method for achieving this?

Comment: You should try yourself to implement it in several different ways - that's how you learn, you can do it! When you get stuck on something ***specific*** come back and ask for help on that.

Comment: To really do it "right" you need to do lexing/parsing, pretty much what you said you don't want to do. To do it "quick" search your string fining each {{#each}} and reads up to {{/each}}. This function would then be recursive so it supports nested entries. If there are a lot of different tags, you need to handle all of those. Writing such a parser is a big undertaking, if you want to show what you've tried, I'd be glad to help, but this is a very big task and I doubt you're going to find someone who will do it for you here. SO is for help, not coder 4 free.

Comment: The 'good' method is writing a parser that is aware of states and nested elements and such-- not regular-expression string replacement.  Why do you not want to write a parser (which I assume you mean by 'full-out compiler')?

Comment: It is not a good idea to use Regex for this kind of problem, and here is [why](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/113237/when-you-should-not-use-regular-expressions). You will need to build a custom parser or use an existing library like [HandleBars.net](https://github.com/rexm/Handlebars.Net).

Comment: @Xiaoy312 I am only planning on using Regex for finding each start tag initially, and at that point I need an extra process that finds the correct end tag. Then I would find all contents in-between and create a object from that information.

Comment: looks like you do need to go with the full compiler way

Comment: @dman2306 I am not sure a full parser is really necessary for what we need to do. Also, I am hard-pressed to find good documentation on writing a parser of this nature. I could possibly be convinced otherwise if someone has documented something similar.

Comment: @NolanP `Regex.Split(source, "({{.+?}}|</?.+?>)")` There you go.

Comment: @NolanP As for parser, I've linked one in my other comment early.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, parsing is looking at things very functionally: regex some characters <>, parse as tag, iterate characters, regex the next <>, get content inbetween tags, covert to string...etc. etc. etc.

This functional, parse-each-time-you-add-a-character approach in my opinion is a byproduct of asking a text editor to perform such tasks as tag recognition, syntax highlighting, etc. Most simply put, a text editor's "purpose" was to expect a "model" object to be a panel full of unicode characters that it could be blissfully ignorant of, and we have grown used to forcing it to 'become intelligent' regarding an object model.

I've been designing my own version of what you are working on after playing around with the "hurt me plenty" HTML tagging inside of Monarch editor ( which is 1. possibly the best we can do in 2017 and 2. stupidly complex.)

The way I am approaching it is not as a text editor, but as a view in the MVC sense that is superficially a text editing surface but is actually a templated, ordered model that is reactive to user behaviors.

Comment: What is your approach for finding blocks (starting and ending tags with content in-between) in your version?

Comment: I don't find tags or content, I get a model object like `var nodes = context.Where(n =>n.ElementText ="h1").ToList<Element>();`